# Weird tick spacing when plotting with time on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a `pandas` time series, which work OK when plotting the timestamps on the x-axis...

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ts = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", freq='15T', closed="left")
vals = np.random.rand(len(ts))
pd.Series(vals, ts).plot()
```

[image]

...but which gives me a very unnatural tick spacing when plotting only the time part on the x-axis:

```py
pd.Series(vals, ts.time).plot()
```

[image]

**How can I turn the x-axis of this second plot into something more human-readable?**

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib and format xaxis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


plt.plot(ts, vals)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Z for that fast answer. Having defined `myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')`, it works when I do `plt.plot(ts, vals)     plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)` as you suggested - but not when I plot the `pandas Series` with `ax = pd.Series(vals, ts).plot()       
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)` (I'd like to keep a handle to the `Axes` object.) Any idea why that is? (it gives me an epoch error)